# Comparing maintenance between '02 SC430 and ES300?

Tags: toyota, maintenance, lexus

I've have an '01 es300 for many years. How does maintenance and parts for this car compare to the maintenance of an '02 SC430?

I recently saw a nice and (apparently) well-maintained '02 sc430 with 75k miles, so that's why I ask.

Thanks.

Comment: So what are you looking for? Cost ? Availability? Service times? Trained monkeys? Sorry service technicians...

Comment: You tell me. If I mention cost, you'll put the question on hold again.

Comment: But generally speaking, I would like to know if parts cost more and if they're readily available.

Comment: Then both of those bits of information are local to you and it is that aspect that causes this type of question to be closed : what is easily available in my area may not be easily found in yours...

Comment: Generally speaking, are parts for an SC430 more expensive than for the ES?

Comment: Should you consider that the parts have a similar price but harder to change ...

Answer (score 2):

I have never personally seen or thought about either of these cars before. Knowing this, I use the internet.

A basic search reveals:
https://repairpal.com/lexus-es300-2001/problems#common-problems

Most commonly complained about thing on the es300 is a mix between oil consumption and failing oxygen delivery components (IAC for example.)

Per https://www.clublexus.com/forums/es-1st-to-4th-gen-1990-2006-179/ which i just learned exists, the front suspension sucks to work on as well.

https://repairpal.com/problems/lexus/sc430#common-problems

For the sc430, its a lot of brake replacement questions and someone trying to replace a head gasket.

Back to https://www.clublexus.com/forums/sc430-2nd-gen-2001-2010-63/ it sounds like these things react to cold weather like reptiles, which could effect you depending on where you live/drive.

It sounds like the sc430 is probably more fun, if it still works, while being harder to maintain. I'll close with recommending an internet-based automated diagnostic utility like https://www.google.com/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is this internet-based automated diagnostic utility free or does he accept checks and money orders?